# Null hostname - Capedwarf

Tags: java, google-app-engine, capedwarf

This code should return the *hostname*, however Capedwarf runtime returns `null` for this code:

```
public String getHostname() {
   ApiProxy.Environment proxyEnvironment = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment();
   Map<String, Object> attributes = proxyEnvironment.getAttributes();
   String hostname = (String) attributes.get(LocalEnvironment.DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME);
   return hostname;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest rather then posting here, open an issue either on CapeDwarf's JIRA or its GitHub project.
So that the issues don't get lost or forgotten.
And even more, try tackling these issues, as they seem to be fairly simple.